# Image Browser Asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, razor, browser

I trying to create ImageBrowser in Asp.net MVC 5. Problem is when I try to switch to another picture.
Here's my code:
In View:

```
@model Katalog.Models.Model
@{
    Model.enumerator = 0;
    int count = Model.ImageList.Count;
    int index = 1;
}
....
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> @index/@count </td>
            ....
        </tr>
        <tr>     
            @using (Html.BeginForm("previous", "Home",FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="number" value="1" />
                    <input value="<" type="submit" onclick="ImageLeft()" class="buttonLeftRight"/>
                </td>
            }          
            <td>@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/ImageViews.cshtml", Model);}</td>                                        
            <td>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("next", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                { 
                    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.ImageList)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.enumerator)
                    <input type="submit"  class="buttonLeftRight" onclick="ImageRight()"/>
                }
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
....
<script>
    function ImageRight()
    { 
        @{ Model.enumerator++; }
    }
</script>
```

My Controller

```
....
public ActionResult next(Katalog.Models.Model model)
{
    model = MyModel;
    return View("Searcher",model);
}
....
```

and my PartialView:

```
@model Katalog.Models.Model
<img id="foto" class="imgFinded" src="@Model.ImageList[@Model.enumerator]"/>
```

When I click Next button my `model.ImageList` is empty. Why?

Comment: Are you expecting to increment the value of `Model.enumerator` when you click on the button (that will never happen) - all you do is pass the original value of `enumerator` to the POST method, because that's the value in the input

Comment: How to do it, Can you show me example? Im new in asp.net world, it's my first app.

Comment: Lots of ways, but with your existing code just use `function ImageRight() { var e = Number($('#enumerator')++; $('#enumerator').val(e); }` to update the value in the hidden input.

Comment: But what is property `ImageList`? The name suggests its a collection in which case `@Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.ImageList)` will not work - look at the html your generating! And why would you even consider sending all that data to the view and sensing ot all back again unchanged anyway - just get the collection again in the POST method.

Comment: Property ImageList is a List<string> whit images decoded whit base64. I dont know how to fill ImageList again it empty in method Next()

Comment: Then that will not work - you would need to create an input for each item in the collection using a `for` loop, but that is not the correct approach - post back only the value for the `enumerator` - your model should not even have that property (all it needs the value to display the current image)

Comment: And you will get far better performance using ajax to post back the `enumerator` and return json containing the image so that you can update the existing `<img>` tag (I assume that is what you have in the view)

Comment: Can u send me link for some helpful tutorial?

Comment: A tutorial for what?

Comment: For ajax, json with my problem in background

Comment: If you edit you question to show how your currently generating the image in the view, and how your populating your model in the GET method that generates that view, then I'll add an answer explaining all your issues including the code showing how you should be doing this using ajax (but its late here so won't be until tomorrow)

Comment: I paste my full view. Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your models `ImageList` property is `null` is because your generating a hidden input `@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.ImageList)` which generates

```
<input name="ImageList" value="System.Collections.Generic.List[]String" .. />
```

which will not bind to your collection in the POST method (when something is not binding, always insect the `name` and `value` attribute of the form controls your generating.

In order to bind to that list you would need to generate an input for each item in the list using a loop.

The other issue is that your scripts does nothing at all. Your model is server side code, and you cannot increment the value of a model property using javascript - you need to send a request to the controller to do that.

Since you sending the collection of images to the view, there is no need to make a request back to the server - you can just update the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag.

Change the model to

```
public class Model
{
    public int InitialIndex { get; set; }
    public int ImageCount { get { return ImageList.Count; } }
    public List<string> ImageList { get; set; }
}
```

and then the view can be just (the partial is unnecessary)

```
<img id="foto" class="imgFinded" src="@Model.ImageList[@Model.InitialIndex ]"/>
<button type="button" id="previous">Previous</button>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
```

and the scripts

```
var imagelist = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ImageList));
var index = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.InitialIndex));
var max = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ImageCount));
var image = $('#foto');

// Set the initial state of the buttons
if (index === 0) {
    $('#previous').prop('disabled', true);
} else if (index === max) {
    $('#previous').prop('disabled', true);
}

$('#next').click(function() {
    $('#previous').prop('disabled', false);
    index++;
    image.attr('src', imagelist[index]);
    if (index === max) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
})
$('#previous').click(function() {
    $('#next').prop('disabled', false);
    index--;
    image.attr('src', imagelist[index]);
    if (index === 0) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    }
})
```

Comment: I have problem with Json.Encode. I add asembly reference System.Web.Helpers to my project and on the top i wrote @using System.Web.Helpers;. And my Visual Studio still dont 
recognizes class Json. What to do ?

Comment: You do not need to do any of that. The `System.Web.Helpers.dll` is already included by default and your `web.config` file should already contain `<pages><namespaces><add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" /> ....` My best guess is that you have some problems with versioning in the `web.config` file. Try creating a new project and in see if the `Json.Encode` method is still causing problems.

Comment: New solution resolve my problem. But Images still not changes.

Comment: What do you mean _But Images still not changes_? Are you referring to when you click on a button?

Comment: Clicking on the buttons do nothing. Ids are correct.I trying put scripts in header and body. Still nothing

Comment: Then what errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. In my work im using mvc 4

Comment: That is because you have not included `jquery-{version}.js` in your view or layout (or if you have, make sure the scripts are immediately before the closing `</body>` tag or wrapped in `$(document).ready()`)

Comment: I added <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> to header. and replace your scripts before the closing </body> still the same error. How to include jquery to the view? Im doing something wrong?

Comment: You cannot possibly get a _Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined_ if that is the case

Comment: But its not really `src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js` is it? - you need to include the path - what you have shown would be generating a 404 in the browser console - it would typically be `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>` but in any case you should be using bundles

Comment: now i have following errors:Uncaught ReferenceError: images is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Searcher:88)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)
Searcher:88 Uncaught ReferenceError: images is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Searcher:88)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)
etc.

Comment: Sorry, see update - should be `image.attr('src', imagelist[index]);` x 2 (but you really need to learn the basics of javascript/jquery, and use your browser tools to debug your code)

Comment: I know its my first Asp.net project. Now its working. You are my Hero ;)

Comment: I have problem with maxJsonLength i set it in web.config on max value () and still the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure what `maxJsonLength` has to do with this question or answer. And what error are you referring to?

Comment: parameter maxJsonLength establishes maximal length of my imagelist, default is to small. Check my other thema here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780077/browsing-images-in-asp-net-mvc-5

Comment: What? All you model contains is a collection of `string` (containing the image url's), plus 2 `int` values. Unless you have 10's of thousands of images, you could not possibly exceed the default limit.

Comment: The default is 2097152 characters, which is equivalent to 4 MB of Unicode string data. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Exactly! If your image urls are typically 30 characters, you would need 70,000 images to exceed the default.

Comment: No. My imagelist contain images encoded with base64, so one image taking half of default value.

Comment: What?? All you need is the url so that you can change the `scr` attribute with the new virtual path. Sending the base64 data is just crazy

Comment: Im new in Asp.net im still lerning I thought it is correct

Comment: Now consol showing: Not allowed to load local resource. That's why i use base64 encode.

Comment: If your images are in (say) the `Images` folder and are named `Image1.png`, `Image2.png` etc, then the values of `ImageList` need to be `new List<string>{ "/Images/Image1.png", "/Images/Image2.png", etc }` and it will work fine

Comment: I taking 2 values that specified with one folder i should open im using FileInfo[] to take all images into one veriable next im filling model.Imagelist with foreach loop, but my path looks like   _file:///E:/Programy%20C#\!Katalog2\Katalog2\MvcApplication1\Views\Home\jpg\1001\1\0_

Comment: Your folder for the images needs to be in the app (what do you think would happen when you publish your app - which wont have a `E:/Programy.... ` folder). Your path needs to be as per my previous comment.

Comment: Normally im working in WPF and i dont know how to take correct path, there is some utility or practices to do it.My folder is virtual catalog in iis but my method taking full name...

Comment: Just create a folder in your app named `Images`, and move your images to it. Then the values your populate the `ImagesList` property with are just `/Images/YourFileName`

Comment: there is 500GB of images. I have that virtual catalog in ~/Vievs/Home/JPG it is correct path?

Comment: It should not be inside you `Views` folder. Just create a new folder named `Images`

Comment: How to programmaticaly take path to each file. Im using 'FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*jpg");


                    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in FileList)
                    {
                       
                        MyModel.ImageList.Add(fileInfo.FullName);
                    }' but this returns full path not to /images

Comment: You need to ask a new question (this thread is already far too long) - and you don't want the full name, you just want the folder name and the file name

Comment: here is new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785384/taking-path-to-iis-virtual-catalog-content

Answer (score 1):

The code @{Model.enumerator++;} and @{Model.enumerator--;} within the two Javascript functions is server side code so it will only be executed once when the view is rendering on the server and before it is passed to the client browser. So triggering the onclick="ImageRight()" by pressing the submit button will not change the server side value.

You could instead try to post the current index to the action in your controller and increment or decrement it depending on which action has been invoked.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Next", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.CurrentIndex)
    <input type="submit"  class="buttonRightLeft"/>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Previous", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    @Html.HiddenFor(a=>a.CurrentIndex)
    <input type="submit"  class="buttonLeftRight"/>
}


public ActionResult Next(int CurrentIndex)
{
    // Get the NEXT image and return as model
    model = MyModel;
    return View("Searcher",model);
}

public ActionResult Previous(int CurrentIndex)
{
    // Get the PREVIOUS image and return as model
    model = MyModel;
    return View("Searcher",model);
}
```