# Taking path to IIS virtual catalog content

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Im trying to take path to IIS virtual catalog but my solution returns me

> file:///E:/Programy%20C#!Katalog2\Katalog2\MvcApplication1\Views\Home\jpg\1001\1\0

My code:

```
public ActionResult Searcher(string symbol, string dekoracja)
    {

        if (symbol != "" && dekoracja != "")
        {
            MyModel.Symbol = symbol;
            MyModel.Dekorajca = dekoracja;
            string path = Server.MapPath(Url.Content(@"~/Images/jpg/" + PathBuilder.Instance.pathBuilder(symbol, dekoracja)));

            DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            try
            {
                FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*jpg");


                foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in FileList)
                {
                    //tylko jpg ma wyswietlac do refaktoryzacji
                    MyModel.ImageList.Add(fileInfo.FullName);
                }
            }...
```

Im new in asp.net and I dont know how to take correct path (~/Vievs/Home/Jpg/...),i need it to put into image src. Symbol and Dekoracja are folder names given in parameter of ActionResult.

```
public class PathBuilder
{
    public static readonly PathBuilder Instance = new PathBuilder();
    public string pathBuilder(string Symbol, string Dekoracja)
    {
        return Symbol + @"\" + Dekoracja + @"\";
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not explained what you expect the result to be. Or what you want the path for (e.g. to use in an `<img>` tag)

Comment: Nor have your explained what `symbol` and `dekoracja` are for, or what your `PathBuilder` is.

Comment: Are you saying you have a subfolder under `\Views\Home\jpg` named `1001` which contains a subfolder named `1`?

Comment: Exacly and i can not change this structure.

Comment: Your images should NOT be in the `/Views` folder - that is for view (as the name suggets) Why can you not change it?

Comment: I mean structure of 1001\1. Ok i put jpg directory into images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images should not be inside your `/Views` folder. Create a new folder in your app (say `Images`), then the code to generate the paths to be used in the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag should be

```
string folder = String.Format("Images/{0}/{1}", symbol, dekoracja); // or whatever you call your folder
var path = Server.MapPath(folder);
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles(); // or GetFiles("*jpg") if it contains other image types
List<string> imageList = files.Select(x => String.Format("/{0}/{1}", folder, x.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: Throwing Exception:
You can not find a part of the path E:\Programy C#\!Katalog2\Katalog2\MvcApplication1\Home\Images\1001\1”. So we stiill creating wrong path.

Comment: Then that folder does not exist - you have not created a folder named `Images` with a subfolder name `1001` which contains a subfolder name `1`

Comment: And what on earth is the `C#\!` bit in that path?

Comment: its my directory for every c# projects ;-)

Comment: You really like to over complicate things :)

Comment: path looks ok but images dont shows                                                      GET http://images/jpg/1001/41/0.jpg net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
images/jpg/1001/41/Thumbs.db:1 GET http://images/jpg/1001/41/Thumbs.db net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
images/jpg/1001/41/0.jpg:1 GET http://images/jpg/1001/41/0.jpg net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: What?? Where are you getting that error. And your missing the leading `/` (which my code adds). And you should be using `DirectoryInfo.Exists()` to check that the path exists first

Comment: I change falowing lines string folder = String.Format("/Images/{0}/{1}", symbol, dekoracja); and source of image shows "src="//Images/jpg/1001/1/0.JPG"". and i think its ok but images won't load.

Comment: No it should just one `/` - `src="/Images/jpg/1001/1/0.JPG"`

Comment: Just drag and drop one of those images into a view and you will see what it generates for the `src` attribute (you may or may not need the leading `~`)

Comment: It works without one backslash in this line List<string> imageList = files.Select(x => String.Format("{0}/{1}", folder, x.Name)).ToList(); thx for help

Comment: That because you added the slash in the code above it - when you used `String.Format("/Images/{0}/{1}"`, ...)` ;)